# Defining default line-wrapping for a specific file

Tags: org-mode

I use org files to write prose and I want to have line-wrapping enabled in those files by default. If possible, I don't want to enable it for all org files, just those used specifically for prose. Is there an org header-arg or command that could make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the following snippet at the end of your org file:

```el
* Local Variables                                       :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# eval: (visual-line-mode 1)
# End:
```

[Here is some documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html)

---

Visual line mode does not modify the buffer, it only modifies how it is displayed. If the window is narrower than a (logical) line, the line is displayed as a number of screen lines. How many depends on the width of the window and if the window width changes, the display of the line changes accordingly.

An alternative is `auto-fill-mode` where a line is split at an appropriate place as you type. This changes the buffer, so widening the window is not going to change the appearance.

The mechanism is the same as for `visual-line-mode`: a local variable block:

```
* COMMENT Local variables                               :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# eval: (auto-fill-mode 1)
# fill-column: 78
# End:
```

See [Auto-fill mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Fill.html) in the Emacs manual and the doc string of `fill-column` with `C-h v fill-column`. Note that the setting of `fill-column` is buffer-local, so you can have different values in different files,

Comment: What if the OP prefers conventional line wrapping  (say at column 78) rather than visual line mode? You probably should also mark the section with a `COMMENT` keyword or a `:noexport:` tag (or both) so that Org mode ignores it in most contexts.

Comment: @NickD, I did put a `:noexport:` tag. How do you do conventional line wrapping?

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you @NickD.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.